# Help to Navigate to other Native App from Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, navigation

Is there any way to navigate to other Native App from Lightning Component?

eg. I've a Facebook Button on my Lightning Component. On Click of button, it should navigate to Facebook Mobile App. Is it possible? If yes, how? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, 
Shruti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using force:navigateToURL? More details here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm?search_text=navigateto